# Ant build denied permission to copy .war file

Tags: web-applications, ant, build-process, build-automation, war

I have a packaged app.war file that I am trying to copy to the webapps folder and I am getting an error:

BUILD FAILED
Failed to copy mywar.war to /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mywar.war due to java.io.FileNotFoundException /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/mywar.war (Permission denied)

Here is the ant code for this:

```
<target name="install" depends="package">
      <copy file="mywar.war" tofile="${webapp.dir}/mywar.war" overwrite="true" />
</target>
```

It is obviously a permissions thing. I can not really solve it by chmod 777 the .war file because the myapp.war will get erased every time, and the new files will have the restrictive permissions applied again.

What if I make the whole webapps dir permissions 777 or something?  That seems like bad practice in terms of security, right?  Or is there an ant command to give the script root permission?  I am using ubuntu if it matters.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I build the WAR file with Ant, and then `su` to root and copy it to the `webapps` folder by hand.

However, you could make the `webapps` folder writable by a particular group, and run Ant as a member of that group.

Comment: Doesn't that take a really long time to do every time you want to try something out?

Comment: The project I work on is relatively stable.  But given that I already have to stop the server before deploying the WAR file anyway, I don't think it's much additional overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `scp` task. You'll need to make sure jsch is on the Ant classpath for it to work. There's documentation from the Ant folks about it.

```
<scp file="mywar.war" todir="root:password@localhost:${webapp.dir}"/>
```